# How can I change the default IComparer in an MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, icomparer

In an ASP.net MVC3 project I have a custom implementation of the IComparer interface. I want to use my comaprer by default when strings are sorted. How can I change the default IComparer for the project?

Comment: I do not want to pass in a comparer during each sort operation. The question is about how to change the comparer at the project level scope.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing IComparable on your type will work in most places